# Non-numerical method of solving the logistic map

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

Is there a way to solve a logistic map $$x_{n+1} = kx_n(1-x_n)$$ without using numerical methods/computers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to explicit formulas, they becomes complicated with the $n$ and no wonder considering the properties of this map. [In this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58045/interpolation-of-a-sequence-of-polynomials-viewed-in-terms-of-q-analogue-powers/58101) are some partial results for the coefficients of iterated series $f(f\ldots f(x)\ldots))\;$ for $f(x)=ax+bx^2+cx^3+\ldots$. Here $a=k$, $b=-k$ and all the others coefficients are equal to zero. For $k=2$ and $k=4$ the solutions can be written out [explicitly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Solution_in_some_cases).

Answer (score 0):

For special values of $k$ (in particular, when [$k=-2$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMapR=-2.html), [$k=2$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMapR=2.html), and [$k=4$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMapR=4.html)), there are explicit expressions for the iterates in terms of trigonometric/exponential functions. On the other hand, you'll need a numerical method anyway to evaluate the logarithm/exponential/arccosine, so I don't really know what you're expecting out of a "non-numerical" method...